# To convert line to circle

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to draw path in WPF with same path Data that I have used in jquery.
For this data the output is like a circle in jquery and straight line in WPF.
Path data that I used is

```
public string PathData
        {
            get
            {
                return "M190.97952270507812,97.1241455078125 C190.89520263671875,97.86524200439453 190.72723388671875,99.34707641601562 190.72723388671875,99.34707641601562 C190.72723388671875,99.34707641601562 190.89520263671875,97.86524200439453 190.97952270507812,97.1241455078125 z";
            }
        }
```

I binded PathData to the `Data` property of  as below.

```
<Path Data="{Binding PathData}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2"/>
```

Actually the path is to draw curves.But in WPF its just a straight line.
What is the problem in my path??Is there any way to convert this straight line to curves??

Comment: This path data will draw a straight line... I think you might miss some of the Transforms...

Comment: This path can never be a circle. Or anything near it. If you look at the first bezier curve, you will find that the four control points are all lined up. The third and fourth control points are even the same. I don't think that any other tool will draw this path as a circle.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the path markup syntax in WPF.

The `C` command expects two control points and one endpoint. Since your second control point and your endpoint are identical in both cases, you get a straight line, but no curve.

"M190.97952270507812,97.1241455078125 C190.89520263671875,97.86524200439453 **190.72723388671875,99.34707641601562 190.72723388671875,99.34707641601562** C190.72723388671875,99.34707641601562 190.89520263671875,97.86524200439453 190.97952270507812,97.1241455078125 z";

Comment: Yes.I have seen that my data draws straight line only.But length of the path gets differ in jqery and WPF.Why this type of changes happening??Is there any way to overcome this??